# Error installing budspencer theme for fish shell

Tags: fish, budspencer

I'm trying to install the Budspencer theme in my fish shell. But when doing, so I keep getting the following error

```
    Last login: Sun Oct  2 19:55:45 on ttys000
    Variables may not be used as commands. In fish, please define a function or use 'eval $budspencer_colors[10]'.
    ~/.local/share/omf/themes/budspencer/fish_greeting.fish (line 2):       $budspencer_colors[10]
                                                                            ^
    in command substitution
        called on line 19 of file ~/.local/share/omf/themes/budspencer/fish_greeting.fish

    in function 'fish_greeting'
        called on line 123 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/HEAD-53f1eba/share/fish/functions/__fish_config_interactive.fish

    in function '__fish_config_interactive'
        called on line 180 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/HEAD-53f1eba/share/fish/config.fish

    in function '__fish_on_interactive'
        called on standard input

    in event handler: handler for generic event 'fish_prompt'

    This is budspencer theme for fish, a theme for nerds.
    Type »budspencer_help« in order to see how you can speed up your workflow.
     1  ✔ 
```

I tried the Budspencer's suggestion for OSX Users' but that didn't solve my problem:

```
brew install --with-default-names gnu-sed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/oh-my-fish/theme-budspencer/issues/37

change fish_greeting.fish line 27

```
echo This is (set_color -b $budspencer_colors[2]
```

to

```
echo This is (set_color -b $budspencer_colors[2] \
```